# How can I make realistic looking homebrew cards?

Tags: dominion, game-design

I am making a homebrew expansion for Dominion and I have been using the GoodNotes app for the card layouts. I thought they looked pretty good until I saw [Asper’s Cards](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=9231.msg284777#msg284777) and was blown away by how good they looked. **Is there any program usable on an ipad browser that can make cards that look like those?**

Comment: Most fan cards on that site, including Asper's, use an [image generator](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=16622.0). But I don't know if works on the iPad (which is why I'm not posting this as an answer).

Comment: I’m voting to close this because recommendation questions are off-topic for this site. However, I think it could be modified to be on-topic if it were looking for general advice on how to make realistic cards, rather than specific apps for Dominion.

Comment: Or one could go the other way and ask what was used to create those specific cards.

Comment: As this question stands it is asking for software recommendations which isn't on topic for this site.

Comment: I’d like to apologize if I offended anyone else who made homebrew cards. I didn’t realize that there were more than just Asper’s.

Comment: @GendoIkari It does work thank you but I don’t think we’re sopposed to answer in the comments.